# Bootstrap confidence interval

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I'm supposed to compute a *one-sided* 90% confidence bootstrap pivotal confidence interval of the mean difference in height between father and son (using the father.son dataset in the UsingR package). I found the smean.cl.boot function when I was searching online and implemented:

`smean.cl.boot(father.son$sheight-father.son$fheight, conf=0.90`

But I wasn't sure if this was one-sided or if it is pivotal (because I'm unfamiliar with pivotal confidence intervals). So I figured I probably am not supposed to use this function and instead use more complicated bootstrap methods, but boot.ci only creates two-sided intervals. Is there any way to alter smean.cl.boot or boot.ci so that I can ensure it is one-sided?